# Windows cmd copy directories and content recursively if the files do not exist

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, xcopy

The question fits in the title:
I want to copy from local storage to a network storage directories and their content, but only the new or updated files with no prompt.
My idea would be to use xcopy

```
xcopy source destination /s /e **only new or updated files**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Windows cmd copy directories and content recursively if the files do not exist**
>
> My idea would be to use xcopy

Unfortunately `XCOPY` really doesn't do this by default very well if at all as far as copy ONLY what does not exist in the destination from the source. Also, `XCOPY` is deprecated per Microsoft and it's recommended to use the `Robocopy` command in place of it, and this especially makes sense to do if you're building a new process.

So while it's your idea to use `XCOPY`, I'm hopeful you'll be willing to use Robocopy for the particular need since it is a Windows native command line tool intended to replace `XCOPY`.

---

[**Robocopy Script Example**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

*(Look over options to ensure all is set for your needs)*

*(Save below logic to a text file and rename to  `<something>.cmd` and double-click to run as needed)*

```
SET SRC="C:\path\source"
SET DEST="C:\path\destination"
SET FName=*.*
SET LOG=C:\Path\Log.txt
::   If you do not want a log file, remove the "/LOG+:%LOG%" below
SET OPT=/PURGE /S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:%Log% /TS /FP
SET CMD=robocopy %SRC% %FName% %DEST% %OPT%
%CMD%
```

---

[**Robocopy Copy and Paste Command Line Example**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

*(Look over options to ensure all is set for your needs)*

```
::   If you do not want a log file, remove the "/LOG+:C:\Path\Log.txt" below
robocopy "C:\path\source" *.* "C:\path\destination" /PURGE /S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:C:\Path\Log.txt /TS /FP
```

---

### Further Resources and Reading

- [**Robocopy**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)